# CSS - Unable to get CSS class working, but inline style does work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert a site to using CSS styles, instead of using tag values such as "width=100%" on table elements and suchlike.

So, I've created various classes, most of which work as I want, but I cannot get one of them working, and can't figure out why.

Specifically, I've created a class as follows:

```
.w_100{width:100%;}
```

and then apply it to a table:

```
<table class="w_100"> ....
```

but the width of the table is only ever displayed as the width of the content within the table, which is much less than 100%.

However, I note that if I use an inline style:

```
<table style="width:100%"> ....
```

then everything works as I expect, but I'd really rather use the class.

So, I'm wondering what silly thing it is that I must be missing or misunderstanding such that the class doesn't do as I expect it to. Any suggestions on how I might get it to work?

Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: we need to see FULL code, we need to check specificity, order, etc

Comment: are you using materializecss/bootstrap or anything like that or do you have any other rule that might be overriding your class? you can see on DevTools the css rules are applied to each element

Comment: Can we see full code please, make a codepen or something so we can play around with it. Also, try using !important

Comment: Let us see the HTML code.

Comment: A [MCVE] would be very helpful here.

Comment: "Talk is cheap, show me the code" - Torvalds, Linus (2000-08-25).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test with your code, i've coloured the table element `black` so you can see the `table`. See your code below running absolutely as expected.

```css
.w_100 {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="w_100">
  <tr>
    <td>How wide are you?</td>
    <td>I'm a 100% mofo!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another test you could do is to check if anything is overriding it. Right click on the table element and inspect the element.

If you are using chrome or most browsers, the right click contextual menu will say **Inspect**.

[image]

If you inspect the element and check the styles panel, you should be able to see anything that could be overriding the table width.

Here is what it should look like...

[image]

Comment: Thank you joshmoto; I'll endeavour to play around with the dev tools some more and see what might be overriding it.

Comment: As for the other comments above, crying about the lack of code, then if you'd read the question then you'd understand that I was simply trying to find out if there is something about tables/width/classes that I wasn't understanding, and no, of course I'm not about to post several thousand lines of code from a project.